# nested promise with request.post

Tags: node.js

I am creating a POST request and if the request is successful, I am creating  a Cisco Spark chatroom (similar to slack). Inside the POST request I am updating part of a variable (array) inside the POST request success and other part of the variable inside the Cisco Spark chatroom creation success.

So I think I need nested promise here so that I have the entire variable available as I need. But I am not sure how to do this.

The original code looks like below:

```
var request = require('request');
var array = [];
  myObj = new Object()
  request.post({
          url: urlServiceNow,
          headers: headers,
          rejectUnauthorized: false,
          requestCert: false,
          agent: false,
      },function (response, err, body){
          var createJSON = JSON.parse(body);
          array.push(createJSON.result.sys_id);
      }.bind(this));
    ciscospark.rooms.create({title: `AppDNotification`})
      .then((room) => {
        array.push(room.id)
        myObj[valEventTime] = array;
        imdb.push(myObj)
        return Promise.all([
          //more code
        ]).catch((error) => {
          console.log(`Error: \n${error}`);
        })
        .then(() => ciscospark.messages.create({
            markdown: messageToSend,
            roomId: room.id
          }))
          .catch( (error) => {
            console.log(`Error: \n${error}`);
        });
      });
```

I updated the code with a .then after the .bind like below

```
request.post({
        url: urlServiceNow,
        headers: headers,
        rejectUnauthorized: false,
        requestCert: false,
        agent: false,
    },function (response, err, body){
        var createJSON = JSON.parse(body);
        array.push(createJSON.result.sys_id);
    }.bind(this))
    .then(() => ciscospark.rooms.create({title: `AppDNotification`}))
    .then((room) => {

       //rest of the code
    })
```

But I am getting error

```
TypeError: request.post(...).then is not a function
```

Please suggest.

Comment: What request library are you using?  It isn't clear what `request` is.  Is it a native node.js object or are you using [request](https://github.com/request/request)?

Comment: edited the post. I am using var request = require('request');

Comment: Then look at the documentation for that library.  There is no support for promises using that library: [Promises & Async/Await](https://github.com/request/request#promises--asyncawait).  You should consider using one of the wrapping libraries such as: [request-promise](https://github.com/request/request-promise).

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the documentation for request, [promises are not supported](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request#promises--asyncawait):

> request supports both streaming and callback interfaces natively. If you'd like request to return a Promise instead, you can use an alternative interface wrapper for request. These wrappers can be useful if you prefer to work with Promises, or if you'd like to use async/await in ES2017.

The documentation continues on to suggest using one of a few different versions that do support promises:

> [request-promise](https://github.com/request/request-promise) (uses Bluebird Promises)
>   [request-promise-native](https://github.com/request/request-promise-native) (uses native Promises)
>   [request-promise-any](https://github.com/request/request-promise-any) (uses any-promise Promises)

Answer (score 1):

Solved this with `request-promise`

```
var rp = require('request-promise');

// Configure the POST request
var optionsPOST = {
    url: urlServiceNow,
    method : 'POST',
    headers : headers,
    rejectUnauthorized: false,
    requestCert: false,
    agent: false
}

rp(optionsPOST)
    .then(function (parsedBody) {
        var post = JSON.parse(parsedBody);
        console.log(post)
        console.log(post.result.sys_id)
        ciscospark.rooms.create({title: `AppDNotification`})
          .then((room) => {

            return Promise.all([
              ciscospark.memberships.create({
                roomId: room.id,
                personEmail: `abc@example.com`
              }),
              ciscospark.memberships.create({
                roomId: room.id,
                personEmail: `abc@example.com`
              }),
            ]).catch((error) => {

              //Handle Error Here
              console.log(`Error: \n${error}`);

            })
            .then(() => ciscospark.messages.create({
                markdown: "Hi",
                roomId: room.id
              }))
              .catch( (error) => {
                console.log(`Error: \n${error}`);
            });
          });
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
        console.log("fail")
    });
```